# NodeJS disable cache

Tags: node.js, express

I now learning NodeJS and I want to use Mustache-express as the template engine (I want to use it instead of Pug, because I used it before on FrontEnd and I think it's a really smart and easy template system). I use nodemon to run the NodeJS server and it's work correctly, it restart every time when I change any file, except the views. When I change anything in the view files, I don't seem it in the requests' responses, only when I restart the NodeJS server. What can I do with that?

I already turned out the cache with the following code:

```
app.disable('etag');
```

Comment: Are you sure that nodemon is configured properly in order to watch the views changes? How do you execute nodemon? I don't think it's a cache issue.

Comment: I simply type the `nodemon` command into command line when I'm in the directory of the NodeJS application.

Comment: if you just started: there is no such thing as "jade". There's "pug", which a year ago was still called "jade" but got threatened with lawsuits to change that name because it was owned by some company that decided to enforce their rights to the name. That said, did you look at the `express` documentation? Disabling cache involves explicitly sending a Cache-Control header, not turning an already-sent header off. Search the docs for Cache-Control.

Comment: I builded the application with the following command `express -c stylus express_example`. And i replaced the `pug/jade` template engine with `mustache-express`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run nodemon with the command `nodemon -e js,html` (if the extension of your views is not html, then replace it)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's now working. Nodemon basically not watching html files only js? P.S.: If anybody else want to add this to package.json to simply start it with `npm-start`, and work correctly, they need to add this: `"scripts":{"start": "nodemon ./bin/www -e js,html"}`.

Comment: No problem. The documentation says: `By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .coffee, .litcoffee, and .json extensions.`

You can find more here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon