# mustache-js views don't auto-refresh with nodemon

Tags: node.js, mustache, nodemon

I've been using nodemon for a while to save me the trouble of restarting the server whenever I edit a file.

Now I switched to using mustache.js templates, and the magically-always-up-to-date ceased to work - I now need to manually restart the server for my changes to take effect.

Is this a bug? Misconfiguration?

To clarify: whenever I edit a .mustache file, I need to manually restart the server to see my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598232/1123) I changed my start script to

`"start": "nodemon -e js,mustache ./server.js",`

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify on which files Nodemon should auto-refresh, you can set **package.json** to start Nodemon with a **nodemon.json** configuration file, that includes the file extensions to watch. For example:

Add to *package.json* file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json"
  },
```

Create *nodemon.json* file:

```
{
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node --harmony"
    },
    "script": "server.js",
    "ext": "js mustache"
}
```

Now when running, you should see that nodemon is watching for *.js* and *.mustache* files:

```
> npm run dev

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] reading config nodemon.json
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mustache 
[nodemon] starting `node --harmony server.js`
[nodemon] child pid: 7740
[nodemon] watching 5 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the html mustache templates **wont** cause the server to restart using nodemon.

But in my case, i can simply **edit** an html mustache template file, **save** it, and **refresh** the page (without restarting the server) and i can see the changes made.

Perhaps, try checking your routing and make sure you are rendering the correct template files.

Comment: I am rendering the correct file ... but on my setup I have to restart the node server for the changes in mustache files to take effect.